# Replacing non-adjacent variables

Tags: manipulate, evaluation

Suppose I have an expression of the form $exp=a\,b\,c\,d\,+\,e\,f\,g\,h$ where all the letters represent real numbers, and I want to replace $a\,c$ in the first term by $w\,x$ and $f\,h$ in the second term by $y\,z$, so Mathematica will actually evaluate $w\,x\,b\,d\,+\,e\,g\,y\,z$. How do I do that?

Comment: `(a b c d + e f g h) // ReplaceAll[{a -> w, c -> x, f -> y, h -> z}]` gives the desired result: `b d w x + e g y z`.

Answer (score 2):

To replace by position rather than value:

```
(a b c d + e f g h) // ReplacePart[{{1, 1} -> w, {1, 3} -> x, {2, 2} -> y, {2, 4} -> z}]
```

> b d w x + e g y z